# Change owner rights Mac OS X

Tags: sudo, chown

I would like to change rights to a users folder on a Mac after migrating to a another domain and I have run the following command after login as admin not the actual user:

sudo chown -R $USER /Users/$USER

after pressing enter I have entered the users password, not the admin password.
Just to clearify I didn´t replace USER with a username.
The question is what did this command do when I omitted the correct username and just entered the password for the user?.
Thanks for answering.

Comment: it wouldn't do anything as it won't find any user with username "USER" in your system.

Comment: Maybe you are asking this in the wrong SE site? Try this instead http://apple.stackexchange.com